# Allowing user to add collections in community without administrator permission in dspace?

Tags: dspace

I am using Dspace 6 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS . By default when an user is created, administrator has to assign him to community so that user can can add collections or items.

I am working on project that needs user to be automatically assigned to all the communities that is there without any administrator permission. Is there any way dspace provides any functionality to do that or can we add/edit module in dspace to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using an authentication service like LDAP or Shibboleth?  If so, you can create a "Special Group" that will auto-assign users.  Search for "Special Groups" on the following page: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Authentication+Plugins#AuthenticationPlugins-ConfiguringShibbolethAuthentication

Comment: I am using password authentication. Should i switch to LDAP or Shibboleth?

Comment: For authentication, you will need to pick the plugin that matches your institutional needs.  For password authentication, there does appear to be a special group configuration.  Search for login.specialgroup on the following page: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Authentication+Plugins#AuthenticationPlugins-AuthenticationbyPassword